# How to upload a file (Laravel)

Tags: php, html, database, laravel

I want to upload a file in Laravel:

1. I put this code in route

   ```
   Route::post('upload', 'myconttest@test')->name('upload');
   ```
2. And put this code in controller

   ```
   function test(Request $request){
       $file=$request->file('myfile');
       $filename=$file->getClinetOriginalName();
       //  $projectname;
       $path='files/';
       $file->move($path,$filename);
   }
   ```

I create a folder in public called files. The code runs without error but the file is not saved.

Comment: What dump of variable  $file shows?

Comment: Has your form the attribute  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` otherwise the form doesn't accept a file

Comment: <form action="/test" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">




<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">

      <p style="text-align:center";>

             <input type="file"  name="myfile"></input>

              <button type="submit" >send</button>

            </p>

          </form>                                                                                                           this is my form

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your form is enabled to upload the file. So check that the following attribute is set or not.

   `<form action"" 'files' => true>`
2. Use the following namespace

   `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;`
3. Then try this:

   `$file = Input::file('myfile');
   $filename = $file->getClinetOriginalName();
   move_uploaded_file($file->getPathName(), 'your_target_path/'.$filename);`

Answer (score 0):

Its a working code please see this

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

         $checkval = implode(',', $request->category);
         $input = $request->all();
         $input['category'] = $checkval;

         if ($request->hasFile('userpic')) {
          $userpic = $input['pic'];
          $file_path = public_path("avatars/$userpic");
          if(File::exists($file_path)) {
              File::delete($file_path);
          }
          $fileName = time().$request->userpic->getClientOriginalName();
          $request->userpic->move(public_path('avatars'), $fileName);
          $input['userpic'] = $fileName;
          Product::create($input);
          return redirect()->route('productCRUD.index')->with('success','Product created successfully');
       }    
    }
```

Comment: You made some mistake it's working code I checked it many times, first you have to check $request ->all() by print_r()

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

First you give folder permission to files folder in public folder

```
function test(Request $request){
    $file=$request->file('myfile');
    $filename=$file->getClinetOriginalName();
    $file->move(public_path().'/files/', $filename);
}
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Answer (score 0):

In controller test function you need to given public path of files folder like

```
$path = public_path('files/');
```

for moving file on given public folder path.

Comment: sorry there was my mistake in public_path() its require a folder path as a parameter